# After redirect to SSL Cookie gets lost

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

If i send a HTTP request to /api , it gets redirected to HTTPS and as Response i am getting 401 back then the Request is forwarded to HTTPS. But the Cookie in the Header gets lost why?

Here is my Config

```
http {
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
        listen      [::]:443 ssl;
        include     ssl/self-signed.conf;
        include     ssl/ssl-params.conf;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=3153600" always;
        server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

        root         /home/cloud;
        index        index.html;
    


    location /api{
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Cookie $http_cookie;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://server:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }




server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;
    proxy_set_header X-Cookie $http_cookie;
        return 307 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```